# Value of resistance used to calculate the MOSFET transductance

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, resistance

What value of resistance is used to calculate the MOSFET transductance in the formula below? $$A_v=\dfrac{v_o}{v_i} = -g_m R$$

This is the circuit in question.

[image]

I am confused on which resistance to use (R1, R2, RD). Some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not calculating the transconductance - this is calculating the voltage gain of the circuit.

gm is the transconductance of the FET and is the change in current through the device caused by a unit change of input voltage.

The output voltage is the gm multiplied by the effective output resistance.

The effective output resistance consists of the resistor Rd in parallel with the internal resistance of the FET (this is omitted in your calculation).  This is normally referred to as Ro.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind why Rd and Ro are in parallel? Would they not be in series? Also, is it safe to assume that Ro is negligible when compared to Rd (4.7 kohms) and omit it from the calculation?

Comment: Any current that comes from the FET has to drive both the physical drain resistor (Rd) as well as the internal resistor; so they are effectively in parallel.  You are correct though in that the Ro maybe 10's or hundreds of kilohms and so has very little effect compared to the external Rd (they are in parallel so a high resistance means it has negligible effect).

Answer (score 1):

It is important that the FET is operated in its linear region because the transconductance is a small-signal parameter. That means: Select a suitable current ID (determined by the gate voltage divider) and a resistor RD which allows some volts for VDS across the FET (app. 0.5 VDD).

More than that, it is not possible to give you exact values for these resistances (and the current iD) because the transcobductance is not a fixed parameter but depends - up to a certain degree - on the current ID as well as the voltage VDS.

That means: You can (should) try to make these measurements (measuring the gain and recalculate gm) for more than one operational point (ID, VDS).